# parse_str() weird behaviour

Tags: php, function, parsing, query-string

I'm having the weirdest issue with the PHP parse_str() function.

When I have a string as following:

```
string(15) "frm_division=58"
```

And I let parse_str work its magic as following:

```
parse_str($str, $result);
```

This is the result for `$result`:

```
array(0) {
}
```

**Example 2**:

```
string(16) "?frm_division=58"
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  ["?frm_division"]=>
  string(2) "58"
}
```

**Example 3**:

```
string(24) "frm_division=58&foo=test"
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

Am I missing something completely obvious?

I'm running PHP 5.4.26.

Comment: Working fine on php 5.4.6 https://eval.in/127083

Comment: [`E_CANNOT_REPRODUCE`](http://3v4l.org/JKVm7)

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrasing. I fixed it. `parse_str` worked fine, the `$result` variable got messed up by a following piece of code.

Thanks everyone!